# Server-side Pagination: total row count for expensive query?

Tags: php, oracle10g, pagination, rowcount

I have a simple query using server-side pagination. The issue is the WHERE Clause makes a call to an expensive function and the functions argument is the user input, eg. what the user is searching for.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  ( SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(numberOfRows) */ 
      query.*, 
      ROWNUM rn FROM 
        (SELECT            
            myColumns 
          FROM 
            myTable 
            WHERE expensiveFunction(:userInput)=1  
          ORDER BY id ASC
        ) query
    )
WHERE rn >= :startIndex 
AND ROWNUM <= :numberOfRows
```

This works and is quick assuming numberOfRows is small. However I would also like to have the total row count of the query. Depending on the user input and database size the query can take up to minutes. My current approach is to cache this value but that still means the user needs to wait minutes to see first result.

The results should be displayed in the Jquery datatables plugin which greatly helps with things like serer-side paging. It however requires the server to return a value for the total records to correctly display paging controls.

What would be the best approach? (Note: PHP)

I thought if returning first page immediately with a fake (better would be estimated) row count. After the page is loaded do an ajax call to a method that determines total row count of the query (what happens if the user pages during that time?) and then update the faked/estimated total row count.

However I have no clue how to do an estimate. I tried count(*) * 1000 with SAMPLE (0.1) but for whatever reason that actually takes longer than the full count query. Also just returning a fake/random value seems a bit hacky too. It would need to be bigger than 1 page size so that the "Next" button is enabled.

Other ideas?

Comment: if i were you i would go with a "load more aproach" - facebook style. This wouldn't envolve counting the results, just fetching until none left. But it would require modifying your jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is as I said in the comments, to use a 'countless' approach. Modify the client side script in such a way that the `Next` button is always enabled and fetch the rows until there are none, then disable the `Next` button. You can always add a notification message to say that there are no more rows so it will be more user friendly.

Considering that you are expecting a significant amount of records, I doubt that the user will paginate through all the results.

Another way is to schedule a cron job that will do the counting of the records in the background and store that result in a table called `totals`. The running intervals of the job should be set up based on the frequency of the inserts / deletetions.

Then in the frontend, just use the count previously stored in `totals`. It should make a decent aproximation of the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your DB engine.
In mysql, solution looks like this :

```
    mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
        -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
    mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Basically, you add another attribute on your select (SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS) which tells mysql to count the rows as if limit clause was not present, while executing the query, while FOUND_ROWS actually retrieves that number.

For oracle, see this article :
[How can I perform this query in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389754/how-can-i-perform-this-query-in-oracle)

Other DBMS might have something similar, but I don't know.

Comment: that method is more of a convenience way to fetch the totals, but not the fastest. see [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting; didn't knew. However, I did used this recently, and I did tested VS count, and got better results. There was either an error in my test, or mysql improved it meanwhile (that article is from 2007). Either way, a test should be made before going with one option or another.

Comment: The issue is not how to count but the fact that it takes very long. I'm looking for solution that hides this from the user by "running the count query in the background" or by estimating row count. The later however seems not to be possible.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. From my past tests, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS was blinding fast (but as specified by Vlad Balmos above, you should do a test first). Therefore, I'm not sure if there is a need to do anything in the background... ? The way I see it is this : (1) add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to your usual query, (2) Call FOUND_ROWS immediately after. (3) send both the rows from step 1 and the count from step 2 to the user.

Comment: @Andrei it all depends on the performance of `expensiveFunction(:userInput)`. Be it `COUNT()` or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` if the function is really computational expensive and there are tons of records it doesn't make any difference if the first takes 10 minutes to complete and the second just 5 min. The user still waits for a considerate amount of time

Comment: He is using subselects. Therefore, the entire (temp) table from subselect is calculated first, and then the limit is applied (at least this is how it works in mysql. Not sure if Oracle does some magic, to send results faster). So in this situation, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS would still avoid calculating the same expensiveFunction twice.

Comment: Also, note that he does a ORDER BY inside a subselect, which I think it makes it impossible to avoid applying expensiveFunction to the full table (and thus making a full table scan).
Another option would be to (maybe) keep running total (i.e. a trigger which calculates expensiveFunction with each insert, and writes it off in a running totals table)

Comment: The magic is that /*+ FIRST_ROWS(5) */ is not a SQL comment but an oracle optimizer hint meaning the query will immediately return after first 5 hits are found making paging fast. Also     SELECT
     count(*)
    FROM 
      mytable
    WHERE expensiveFunction(:userInput)=1; is just as slow so no issue with order by or subselects.

Comment: ok. In this situation, I see the following options : (1) See the article referenced in the answer; maybe you can calculate the count at the same time with the query, without incurring any additional cost, and therefore, eliminating the necessity to hide the loading time. (2) show the user something like "10 rows out of (loading...)". Depending on what that data means, few users will actually care about what the total count is, so this solution could work. (3) Maintain running totals as explained in a previous comment above. (4) Maybe a bit overkill, but you could also use a materialized view.

Comment: Can you try SELECT add_query_hint_here * FROM mytable WHERE expensiveFunction(:userInput)=1; VS the exact same query, but with an order by at the end ? My expectation is for the second version to be much much slower.

Comment: Even so that Order By is absolutely required for correct paging I checked anyway and it has no considerable effect on query time. Why should it? Ordering 1 page (like 5-10) of records will always be very, very fast. EDIT: ok you are right if I leave the paging part away it is slower with the order by but in the original query posted (the one that matters) it has no real effect.

Comment: Plus in the counting of total records ordering will be omitted anyway, eg. select count(*) FROM mytable WHERE expensiveFunction(:userInput)=1;

Comment: The idea was this : if you have an "ORDER BY" clause, then that query hint of yours is useless; this is because, in order to do the ORDERing, the engine has to calculate anyway, the entire resultset (you want to get the first 5 results, but how can the engine know which ones are actually the FIRST 5, without ordering the entire resultset?). 
This in turn, was important because, if the engine IS actually calculating everything in order to give you those 5 results, then it makes sense to apply something like SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (or the equivalent), to avoid re-running an expensive count query.

Comment: ...otherwise (if the above is false), I would go with (2) if possible, or (3) as described above.