# PHP pagination with wrong type page and how to set pagination no show 5 by 5

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using PHP Pagination for my data with Oracle database.

```
if(isSet($_GET['search']))
{
    $strSQL = oci_parse($c1, "
        SELECT
        T.TONEID,
        T.TONE_NAME,
        T.ACTIVE,
        TO_CHAR(T.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
        T.ADDEDBY
        FROM
        WA_BT_TBL_TONE T
        WHERE
        TONE_NAME LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'
        ORDER BY T.DATEADDED DESC
    "); 
}
else
{
    $strSQL = oci_parse($c1, "
        SELECT
        T.TONEID,
        T.TONE_NAME,
        T.ACTIVE,
        TO_CHAR(T.DATEADDED, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DATEADDEDS,
        T.ADDEDBY
        FROM
        WA_BT_TBL_TONE T
        ORDER BY T.DATEADDED DESC
    "); 
}
oci_execute ($strSQL,OCI_DEFAULT);

$Num_Rows = oci_fetch_all($strSQL, $dData); 

$Per_Page = 10;

$Page = $_GET["Page"]; 
if(!$_GET["Page"]) 
{ 
    $Page=1; 
} 

$Prev_Page = $Page-1; 
$Next_Page = $Page+1; 

$Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page); 
if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page) 
{ 
    $Num_Pages =1; 
} 
else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0) 
{ 
    $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ; 
} 
else 
{ 
    $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1; 
    $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages; 
} 

$Page_End = $Per_Page * $Page; 
if($Page_End > $Num_Rows) 
{ 
    $Page_End = $Num_Rows; 
}

$no = 1;

if($Num_Rows > 1)
{
    for($i=$Page_Start;$i<$Page_End;$i++)
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dData['TONE_NAME'][$i]; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
```

HTML Pagination

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
    if($Prev_Page)
    {
        echo " <a href='?Page=$Prev_Page'>Back</a> ";
    }

    for($i=1; $i<=$Num_Pages; $i++)
    {
        if($i != $Page)
        {
            echo "<a href='?Page=$i'>$i</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b><a> $i </a></b>";
        } 
    } 
    if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
    {
        echo " <a href ='?Page=$Next_Page'>Next</a> ";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

The code above is working good, until I got the table show empty row when I try to edit page manually with text or number -5. Example: http://example.com/Page=blabla
[image]

My questions:
1. How to prevent the data show with row empty if We edit the page manually with strange value, example with text or -5?
2. Is it possible to limit the page number show 5 by 5?

[image]

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oracle 11g

Comment: Any advice Sir?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for pagination in php I will recommend use two queries:

1. one to get count of all elements

`SELECT count(*) from tableName`

If count of elements is 0 for blablabla then you don't process second query

2. second to get rows from e.g. 10 to 20 on 2 page

`SELECT field1, field2 FROM tableName`

with LIMIT for selected page.

This strategy should solve your issue.

I found for you something that could help: [How can I perform this query in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389754/how-can-i-perform-this-query-in-oracle)

Edit:

I'm not good at oracle but here I just wanted to say that get all records on every page is not good idea. I found something that could help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Does Oracle support `LIMIT` ?

Comment: I'm not good at oracle but here I just wanted to say that get all records on every page is not good idea. I found something that could help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html